Power BI Report Builder - Older Version Required
The latest Power BI Report Builder (version 15.7.1811.11) does not allow me to connect to my Azure SQL Database with "Active Directory Password".... Getting the below error.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
The type initializer for 'Azure.Core.ClientOptions' threw an exception.The type initializer for 'Azure.Core.ClientOptions' threw an exception.

Anyone know what this can be, for a work around I am looking for the previous version of Power BI Report Builder online, but I cant find it anywhere!

try to upgrade your .Net framework to 4.8 or latest version

".NET Framework 4.8 or a later update is already installed on this computer." - Got this message when I tried to install 4.8
